# How to start jupyter notebook (or run 1 command) when GCP Starts up

Tags: 20.04, ssh, google

I have a GCP instance. Currently, I login using the username@ip address with a SSH file for auth.

Then once I login using terminal, I run this command manually

`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser & disown`

I want to do something like, after I hit "start" button on google cloud VM page, jupyter notebook starts. How can I do it?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76385199/111175?